# Having trouble fixing key Pressed event function

Tags: java

Below is a code I'm having trouble fixing a bug with. I'm not able to move objects using arrow key properly. Whenever I use arrow keys to move the object on screen, it moves a few pixels and then stops. Keys stop working. I'm using eclipse compiler.
Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ch10_Ex06_Draw_Star_Additions extends GraphicsProgram
{
    public void init ()
    {
        slider  = new JSlider (1, 150, 30);

        box = new JComboBox  ();
        box.addItem         ("White");
        box.addItem         ("Black");
        box.addItem         ("Red");
        box.addItem         ("Green");
        box.addItem         ("Blue");
        box.addItem         ("Orange");
        box.addItem         ("Yellow");
        box.setEditable     (false);
        box.setSelectedItem ("White");

        textField = new JTextField (20);
        textField.addActionListener (this);

        add (new JLabel  ("Small"), SOUTH);
        add (slider,                SOUTH);
        add (new JLabel  ("Large"), SOUTH);
        add (new JButton ("Clear"), SOUTH);
        add (new JLabel  ("Text"),  SOUTH);
        add (textField,             SOUTH);
        add (box,                   SOUTH);

        setBackground (Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        addActionListeners  ();
        addKeyListeners     ();
        addMouseListeners   ();
    }

    public void keyPressed   (KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)
            removeAll ();

        gobj = getElementAt (X, Y);

        if (gobj != null)
        {
            switch (e.getKeyCode ())
            {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:        gobj.move(0, -5);   break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:      gobj.move(0, +5);   break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:      gobj.move(-5, 0);   break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:     gobj.move(+5, 0);   break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e)
    {
        X = e.getX();
        Y = e.getY();

        star = new GStar    (slider.getValue());
        star.setFilled      (true);
        star.setColor       (getCurrentColor());
        star.setFillColor   (getCurrentColor());
        add (star, e.getX(), e.getY());
    }

    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e)
    {
        point   = new GPoint    (e.getPoint());
        gobj    = getElementAt  (point);
    }

    public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (gobj != null)
        {
            gobj.move (e.getX() - point.getX(), e.getY() - point.getY());
            point = new GPoint (e.getPoint());
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand() == "Clear") 
            removeAll ();

        if (e.getSource() == textField)
        {
            GLabel label = new GLabel (textField.getText());
            String str = "Arial-" + slider.getValue() / 2;
            label.setColor (getCurrentColor());
            label.setFont(str);
            add (label,  X + star.getWidth()  , Y + star.getHeight()/4);
        }
    }

    private Color getCurrentColor()
    {
        String name = (String) box.getSelectedItem();
             if (name == "Red")     return Color.RED;
        else if (name == "Green")   return Color.GREEN;
        else if (name == "Blue")    return Color.BLUE;
        else if (name == "Orange")  return Color.ORANGE;
        else if (name == "Yellow")  return Color.YELLOW;
        else if (name == "Black")   return Color.BLACK;
        else                        return Color.WHITE;
    }

    private JTextField  textField;
    private JSlider     slider;
    private JComboBox   box;
    private GObject     gobj;
    private GPoint      point;
    private GStar       star;
    private int         X, Y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object is moving away, out of the range of "X" and "Y" which are only obtained when you click on an object. You should probably save the object returned by getElementAt(X, Y) during the click into a member variable, say, selectedObject, and then use that to move it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying to my post but I'm quite not sure what you are trying to say. Could you just write 2-3 lines of code to explain me. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can see that you are saving the X and Y values in the mouseClicked event. Now when you press an arrow key (say, right arrow), each time the handler is invoked, the method getElementAt(X, Y) returns the object at the last clicked position (not necessarily the last clicked object) and moves it to the right. This repeats a few times. Then what happens is the position of the object moved so much that its not in (X, Y) anymore. so getElementAt(X, Y) does not return anything. So gobj is null. I hope you understood now.